# Github actions failing to pip install python package with dependency on submodule python package

Tags: python, pip, package, github-actions

I am trying to run [this github actions workflow](https://github.com/A-Baji/discordAI/actions/runs/3820076134/workflow) but it's not able to pip install my package. My package contains a [submodule to another pip package](https://github.com/A-Baji/discordAI/pull/2/files#diff-cc05a665b8dfeb220591ef62b4c294a52d4886e5d95fe72d9cbc63ff85fc6704), which is listed in my [requirements.txt](https://github.com/A-Baji/discordAI/pull/2/files#diff-4d7c51b1efe9043e44439a949dfd92e5827321b34082903477fd04876edb7552). When I pip install locally, everything works fine, but when github actions tries to pip install it, it [fails](https://github.com/A-Baji/discordAI/actions/runs/3820076134/jobs/6498119615#step:5:31) with the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discordAI-modelizer (from discordai) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for discordAI-modelizer
```

The checkout step shows that the [submodule was initialized](https://github.com/A-Baji/discordAI/actions/runs/3820076134/jobs/6498119615#step:2:135), and I ran a [test run](https://github.com/A-Baji/discordAI/actions/runs/3820076134/jobs/6498119615#step:4:1) where I ran `ls -la` in the submodule directory after the checkout step and all the files were there.

Is there a step I'm missing to get this to work? Or is there some kind of workaround I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, make sure that you correctly specified your package name inside your `setup.py` file, then if the package that you're using is hosted on a GitHub repo you should include the `git+` prefix on your `setup.py` file to be able to install the package from the GitHub repo like the below's peace of code:

```
    install_requires=[    
'your_package @ git+https://github.com/user/your-package.git#egg=yourpackage'
]
```

Also, if the package that you trying to install has a dependency on another package located in a submodule, you should specify the submodule in the dependency specification file by putting `&subdirectory=submodule` at the end of the above endpoint that I mentioned.

In the end, if you're still facing this issue try to install it manually using the `pip` command like the below's command line to see if you may get any errors that may help you to solve this issue:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/your-package.git#egg=your_package&subdirectory=submodule
```